# Regex Pattern with Spaces in Java

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-greedy

I want to identify that a string passed into a function is a valid string. In doing so, the string is a string of Polynomials that must have spaces between them.

These are valid:

```
3x^7 3445x^233 3x 34 355
0
+3x^7 x^6 +3445x^233 -3x +34355 x^2
```

These are not valid:

```
+3x^7+3445x^233-3x +34355
+3x^-7+3445x^233-3x +34355
```

One space does not count. Every pattern has to have a space between. How do I select the valid string without selecting any items from the invalid strings?

I've tried this...

```
while (str.hasNext()) {
    str.findInLine("([\\+-]*?\\b\\d+)x\\^([\\+-]*?\\d+\\b)"
            + "|([\\+-]*?\\b\\d+)x|([+-]*?\\d+)|\\^(\\d+)");
    MatchResult m = str.match();

    // When the term has a valid coefficient and power ie 3x^3
    if (m.group(1) != null) {
      coefficient = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
      power = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
      this.addTerm(coefficient, power);
    }
    // When the term ends in x ie 3x
    else if (m.group(3) != null) {
      coefficient = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
      this.addTerm(coefficient, 1);
    }
    // When the term has no x ie -3
    else if (m.group(4) != null) {
      coefficient = Integer.parseInt(m.group(4));
      this.addTerm(coefficient, 0);
    }
    // When the term has no coefficient ie x^3
    else if (m.group(5) != null) {
      power = Integer.parseInt(m.group(5));
      this.addTerm(1, power);
    }
}
```

As you can tell, my regex is accepting all valid groups without identifying the spaces.

Thanks!

Comment: `"([+-]?((\\d+x?)|x)(\\^\\d+)?(\\s+|$))+"` validates provided valid and not valid strings as expected. You can try to split string by spaces and analyze each expression separately to simplify further parsing.

Answer (score 0):

While attempting to solve this problem I accidentally made it to where it would parse the invalid expressions as well... valid. With some simple logic, you could weed out the dirty expressions but this may work. I'll continue to see if I can find a better solution.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner scan = new Scanner("+3x^7 3445x^233 3x 34 355");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner("+3x^7+3445x^233-3x +34355");

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String s = scan.next();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((?:[\\+\\-]*?)?\\d+)?x?(?:\\^(\\d+))?");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

        while (m.find())
            System.out.println(m.group());

    }

}

}
```

This can be used to see if expression are valid or not:

```
if(!s.matches("(?:[\\+\\-]*\\d*x?\\^?\\d*)") && !s.equals(""))
```

**EDIT II**

Here's an example of me extracting "parts" from the equation:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner("+3x^7 3445x^233 3x 34 355");
    //Scanner scan = new Scanner("+3x^7+3445x^233-3x +34355");

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String s = scan.next();

        if(!s.matches("(?:[\\+\\-]*\\d*x?\\^?\\d*)") && !s.equals(""))
            System.exit(0);

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:([\\+\\-]*?)?(\\d+))?x?(\\^(\\d+))?");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

        while (m.find())
            for(int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); i++)
                if(m.group(i) == null)
                    continue;
                else
                    System.out.println(m.group(i));

    }

}

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Original:
+3x^7

Parts:
+
3
^7

Original:
3445x^233

Parts:
3445
^233

Original:
3x

Parts:
3

Original:
34

Parts:
34

Original:
355

Parts:
355
```

I hope this leads you in the right direction.